# How to maximize my Emacs frame on start-up?

Tags: frames

*Is there a way to maximize my window on start-up?*

Currently, I hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> on my keyboard but it is very bothersome to do that every time.

I am using Emacs 24.4 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I did not know the key combination to maximize emacs. Thanks for that and also the answer below worked out!

Comment: From where did you find out the combination `<kbd>![Windows Key][oldwinlogo]</kbd>` This does not work for me :-(

Comment: To circumvent the problem, one could use desktop-save-mode, so that you set your favorite frame sizes once and they are reproduced in the next emacs session automatically.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I have another method, which I have tested with Emacs 24.3 and 24.4, as well as on both Windows and GNU/Linux. I have placed the following in [my init file](https://github.com/501st-alpha1/emacs):

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(fullscreen . maximized))
```

I believe this was modified slightly from a StackOverflow answer I found a while ago, but I can't seem to find it again now.

**Edit:** Another bonus of this method is that it also applies to new clients that connect to your Emacs server (with e.g. `emacsclient -c`).

Comment: +1 for the precise answer. If I could accept this as answer again - I really would!

Comment: I like this solution using `emacsclient`, but there are some frames that starting them maximized would prevent to use them correctly, like the **ediff control panel**, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @marcanuy: I don't know of a solution off the top of my head, but it might be worth posting a new question for that.

Comment: @marcanuy You can use `initial-frame-alist`. Like the name implies, this will only maximize the initial frame.

Answer (score 44):

Adjust the `...-frame-alist` in your init file to tell Emacs how to maximize the frame.  You also have multiple options for how, exactly, to maximize it.

### `alist` options

You have two `...-frame-alist` options:

1. `default-frame-alist` (as in @Scott Weldon's answer)
2. `initial-frame-alist`

If you use `default-frame-alist`, it will maximize *all* frames: both the first one and any others you create.  That may not be what you want (or maybe it is: who am I to judge?).

If you use `initial-frame-alist`, it will maximize *only* the frame that Emacs creates at startup, but will not touch any subsequent frames you create.

### maximization options

For your maximization options, see [this node of the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Size-Parameters.html#Size-Parameters) for details.  The short version is that you can set the `fullscreen` parameter to:

- `fullwidth` (make the frame as wide as possible, don't touch the vertical)
- `fullheight` (make the frame as tall as possible, don't touch the horizontal)
- `fullboth` (set height and width to to size of the screen)
- `maximized` (make it, well, maximized)

The difference between `fullboth` and `maximized` is that you can resize the former with the mouse, while with the latter you cannot.

### example

So, for example, these lines will 1) create a maximized initial frame, and 2) create fullheight (but not fullwidth) frames on every subsequent frame:

```
(add-to-list 'initial-frame-alist '(fullscreen . maximized))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(fullscreen . fullheight))
```

Comment: Indeed `initial-frame-alist` is much more useful than `default-frame-alist` when one uses tools like ediff.

Comment: `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(fullscreen . maximized))` is not the best answer. I confirm what another answer said (Dan): `(add-to-list 'initial-frame-alist '(fullscreen . maximized))` is the way to have this work well.

Answer (score 35):

On Emacs 24.4, `(toggle-frame-maximized)` toggles the maximized state of the current frame.

See also, the [Maximize Emacs on start up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763847/maximize-emacs-on-start-up-not-the-fullscreen) question on stackoverflow and the [Full Screen](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FullScreen) page on the EmacsWiki.

Comment: This works with castlemacs on mac. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks this works for me on emacsclient where as the add to frame list doesn't.

Answer (score 17):

To startup Emacs maximised, add to your init file:

```
;; Start maximised (cross-platf)
(add-hook 'window-setup-hook 'toggle-frame-maximized t)
```

In case you want to go full screen or, as they say now, *distraction free* mode:

```
;; Start fullscreen (cross-platf)
(add-hook 'window-setup-hook 'toggle-frame-fullscreen t)
```

**NOTE**: *This works in Windows too.*

Comment: Finally! The `t` argument to `add-hook` (to make `toggle-frame-fullscreen` run last, not first) was the missing ingredient for me that made it work.

Answer (score 12):

@Constantine's answer already covers how this can be achieved by modifying your init-file (if you use Emacs 24.4).

If you start Emacs from the command line, from the dash, or from a launcher like [Synapse](https://launchpad.net/synapse-project) or [krunner](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Krunner), you can specify the `-mm` option (short for `--maximized`) to achieve the same result:

```sh
emacs -mm
```

The `-mm` option was first [introduced in Emacs 23.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/news/NEWS.23.2), so this solution is not limited to the latest stable release.

---

What distinguishes this solution from other suggestions posted here (all of which are great) is that it allows you to decide on a case-by-case basis whether you want the Emacs frame maximized at start-up or not.

If you want a more permanent solution, you can set up an `alias` for the command shown above by adding the following to your `.bashrc`:

```sh
alias emacs='emacs -mm'
```

Comment: Another benefit of this solution is that emacs starts already maximized. Init file workarounds make it switch to maximized during the startup, which is kind of annoying.

Comment: To add to this answer: `emacs -fs` starts Emacs maximized to the full screen, or maximally maximized to the max.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following:

```
(when (eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
  (defun x11-maximize-frame ()
    "Maximize the current frame (to full screen)"
    (interactive)
    (x-send-client-message nil 0 nil "_NET_WM_STATE" 32 '(2 "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ" 0))
    (x-send-client-message nil 0 nil "_NET_WM_STATE" 32 '(2 "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT" 0)))
  (run-with-idle-timer 0.01 nil 'x11-maximize-frame)
  )

(when (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
  (w32-send-sys-command 61488)
)
```